# NamedTuple is shared across variables

Tags: python, namedtuple

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List, Set, Tuple, Dict

class EmbeddingInfoStruct(NamedTuple):
    emb_names : list[str] =[]
    idx_in_data: list[int] =[]
    emb_dim: list[int] =[]

info1 =EmbeddingInfoStruct()
info1.emb_names.append("name1")

info2=EmbeddingInfoStruct()

print("info1 address = ", id(info1), ", info2 address = " ,id(info2))
print (info1)
print (info2)
```

output of print :

```
info1 address =  2547212397920 , info2 address =  2547211152576
EmbeddingInfoStruct(emb_names=['name1'], idx_in_data=[], emb_dim=[])
EmbeddingInfoStruct(emb_names=['name1'], idx_in_data=[], emb_dim=[])
```

Surprisingly info1 and info2 both share the same value. I'd expect info2.emb_names to be empty. Why does NamedTuple behaves like it's a "static  class"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: This is a well-known gotcha in Python.

Comment: @RandomDavis I wouldn't say it's unrelated. The problem is the same in both cases: the thing you think gets created on every call is actually just a reference to the same mutable value.

Comment: Specifically, the metaclass used by `NamedTuple` (which is a *function*, despite it being used like a class) uses the values assigned to what otherwise look like class attributes in the same way a default argument value is used.

Comment: I would strive to use named tuples for data that really is immutable, even if the immutable fields of a tuple are allowed to be mutable values like lists. If something is supposed to be mutable, make it *look* mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mistook `NamedTuple` from the `typing` module, describing the type of a named tuple for type hinting purpose, and the named tuple you can get from `namedtuple()` from the `collection` package (see [the collection documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)).

Here, you are actually changing class member of your `EmbeddingInfoStruct`, thus the "static class" behavior.

---

Using this, your class declaration would rather look like

```py
from collections import namedtuple
EmbeddingInfoStruct = namedtuple("EmbeddingInfoStruct",["emb_names", "idx_in_data", "emb_dim"],defaults=[list(),list(),list()])

info1 = EmbeddingInfoStruct()
```

You will, however, probably fall into the pitfall of "mutable" as default arguments, as explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: you are absolutely  correct , I used wrong class.

Comment: If this answer is the solution to your problem, please mark it as such to help people who would stumble on this question to find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

As said by others, the problem is the mutable default. You could use a dataclass with a field providing a default factory. See

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field